Error during NVIDIA drivers installation using recommended tool ubuntu-drivers
Cannot successfully install drivers using the documentation and recommended tool on ubuntu server 22.04.
Official guide: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation
Run sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu nvidia:535-server and sudo apt install nvidia-utils-535-server. After reboot run nvidia-smi and get this:
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

When run modprobe nvidia getting:
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-106-generic

When run lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)", getting:
2a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation AD102 [GeForce RTX 4090] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 167c
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

Using other ways like local runfile work fine. So why the recommended way does not work?
UPDATE: could solve it, there are 2 distinct problems. 1st is that, it appears, drivers with -server suffix do not work properly with consumer-grade GPUs like Nvidia 4090. 2nd is that there is nouveau in Kernel modules even though I explicitly blacklisted it. For some reasons, blacklisting does not work strictly if kernel module is already built. Also, running sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu nvidia:535 does not force kernel module rebuilt. What worked is purge nvidia files from the system:
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

And reboot. Here the autoinstall did the trick, trying to directly specify a particular version with nvidia:535 fallback on nouveau in my case. After this, it is possible to re-run
sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu nvidia:535

with a particular version specified and everything works.

purge+autoinstall worked for me.

For me, --gpgpu was the culprit. The -server suffix was not a problem.
The following command worked:
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:535-server

